# Error inicio de sesión, Linux Deepin 15.5

Tags: linux

tengo un problema con el inicio de sesión en linux deepin, carga hasta el login y puedo ingresar la contraseña normalmente, pero al darle enter o click en entrar no hace nada. No puedo ingresar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Prueba si el LOGIN con la terminal de texto funciona siguiendo estos pasos: 1. CTRL+ALT+F2 (esto te tiene que llevar a la consola no-gráfica)
2. Intenta el LOGIN
3. Intenta el PASSWORD Si entra sin problemas, es un problema del entorno gráfico, si no, reporta el error que tienes para ver qué podría ser.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz efectivamente era un error de entorno gráfico, suele suceder en algunos sistemas operativos Gnu Linux por lo investigado. muchas gracias.

Comment: Me pasó algo igual pero en Arch-Linux al instalarle el entorno de escritorio deepin.
El problema era que el usuario estaba mal configurado, no tenía el directorio en **/home**, por ejemplo si el usuario es "tae" debe existir un directorio tae en la ruta /home/tae de esa manera, fijate si tienes confurado adecuadamente tu usuario con los directorios y permisos necesarios.

Answer (score 1):

Tuve le mismo problema, el tema es que estaba creando el directorio /home en una partición NTFS que uso en Win10; resulta que cuando Windows se apaga no "libera" las particiones, por lo cual Linux no podia crear la carpeta de usuario en /home.
La solución es ingresar a windows, y en la consola, como administrador ejecutar el comando powercfg -h off. Con eso ya Linux probra crear el directorio de usuario y todo funcionará bien.